# Weird TableView error while getting data from different models

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'm working on a TableView who should display data from different kind of models. When I use one model everything works fine. But as soon as I add other models it turns out erroneous at `OPTable.getColumns().addAll(...);` . I can't make sense of the error description.

`The method addAll(int, Collection<? extends TableColumn<capture#4-of ?,?>>) in the type List<TableColumn<capture#4-of ?,?>> is not applicable for the arguments (TableColumn<Ofenproben,String>, TableColumn<Ofenproben,String>, TableColumn<Auftrag,String>, TableColumn<Ofenproben,String>, TableColumn<ModelConverter,String>, TableColumn<ModelConverter,String>, TableColumn<ModelConverter,String>)`

Here is my TableView:

```
TableView<?> OPTable= new TableView();
     OPTable.setEditable(true);
     OPTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
     OPTable.setColumnResizePolicy((param) -> true );

     TableColumn<Ofenproben, String> TLPCol = new TableColumn<Ofenproben, String>("TLP Typ");
     TableColumn<Ofenproben, String> LosCol= new TableColumn<Ofenproben, String>("Losbezeichnung");
     TableColumn<Auftrag, String> AKBCol = new TableColumn<Auftrag, String>("Auftragskurzbezeichnung");
     AKBCol.setPrefWidth(350);
     TableColumn<Ofenproben, String> ProbenNrCol = new TableColumn<Ofenproben, String>("Probennummer");
     TableColumn<ModelConverter, String> OfenCol = new TableColumn<ModelConverter, String>("Ofen");
     TableColumn<ModelConverter, String> PlatzNrCol = new TableColumn<ModelConverter, String>("Platz");
     TableColumn<ModelConverter, String> ProbeFertigCol = new TableColumn<ModelConverter, String>("Proben fertig");
     //Sub Columns
     TableColumn<ModelConverter, Boolean> EinsCol = new TableColumn<ModelConverter, Boolean>("1");
     TableColumn<ModelConverter, Boolean> ZweiCol = new TableColumn<ModelConverter, Boolean>("2");
     TableColumn<ModelConverter, Boolean> DreiCol = new TableColumn<ModelConverter, Boolean>("3");
     TableColumn<ModelConverter, Boolean> VierCol = new TableColumn<ModelConverter, Boolean>("4");

     // Sub columns an Proben Fertig anfügen
     ProbeFertigCol.getColumns().addAll(EinsCol, ZweiCol, DreiCol, VierCol);

     //Daten einfügen von Klasse Ofenproben
     TLPCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("TLP"));
     LosCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Los"));
     AKBCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("AKB"));
     ProbenNrCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ProbenNr"));
     OfenCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Ofen"));
     OfenCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<ModelConverter> forTableColumn());
     OfenCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<ModelConverter, String> event) -> {
            TablePosition<ModelConverter, String> pos = event.getTablePosition();

            String newOfen = event.getNewValue();

            int row = pos.getRow();
            ModelConverter mc = event.getTableView().getItems().get(row);

            mc.setOfen(newOfen);
        });
     PlatzNrCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PlatzNr"));
     PlatzNrCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<ModelConverter> forTableColumn());
     PlatzNrCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<ModelConverter, String> event) -> {
            TablePosition<ModelConverter, String> pos = event.getTablePosition();

            String newStellplatz = event.getNewValue();

            int row = pos.getRow();
            ModelConverter mc = event.getTableView().getItems().get(row);

            mc.setStellplatz(newStellplatz);
        });
     EinsCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("checked"));
     ZweiCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("checked"));
     DreiCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("checked"));
     VierCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("checked"));
     EinsCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(EinsCol));
     ZweiCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(ZweiCol));
     DreiCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(DreiCol));
     VierCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(VierCol));

     //ObservableList<ModelConverter> list = getProbenList();
     //OPTable.setItems(list);
     OPTable.getColumns().addAll(TLPCol, LosCol, AKBCol, ProbenNrCol, OfenCol, PlatzNrCol, ProbeFertigCol);
```

Please help and give me an code example to solve this problem.

Comment: a) specify the item type as `OPTable` in the declaration instead of using `?` b) the first type parameter of the column has to match the type parameter for the TableView. You're using `Ofenproben`, `ModelConverter` ***and*** `Auftrag` however.

Comment: Yes. As soon as I select one type the other types can't be implemented. The only solution is to create different tableViews with each specific type. But that seems a huge effort because type "Auftrag" is just one column. Is there anotherway?

Comment: @Sewjin It doesn't make sense to have different types. The first type parameter of the `TableColumn` is the same as the type parameter for the `TableView`, and it's the type of the object represented by each row. Since the object is constant across any row, it has to be the same thing for all the columns. Why do you think you want different types here?

Comment: Okay, it seems if I use a DAO for my different models and use the DAO as type for the TableView it might work. I'll figure it out. So there is absolutly no way to get different column types in one tableView?

Comment: You can have different column types; just not different types of items in the table. If you have a `TableView<S>` (so all the *rows* are of type `S`), you can have `TableColumn<S,T1>` (cells in that column have items of type `T1`), `TableColumn<S,T2>` (cells in that column have items of type `T2`), etc etc. There is something fundamental you are missing here, but I don't really understand what it is. I guess the question is: what type of objects are you putting in the table's `items` list? (`opTable.getItems().add(xxx)`: what type of thing is `xxx`?)

Comment: I use an observable list to get my data into the tableview  `OPTableB.setItems(DBController.ProbenAuftragList); `

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. What is `ProbenAuftragList` (and *please* use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java))? And specifically what is the *type* of the elements in the list. (If you call `ProbenAuftragList.get(0)`, for example, what type of object does it return?) Whatever that type is, that is the type you should use for the `TableView`.